# Custom Password Reset

Tags: users, email, password

I am building a function that should send the user an email with a password-reset-link in it (I am just using it after registration because I don't want my user to set his password while registrating).

I tried the following code in a wordpress template, where it worked just fine. The mail got sent successfully. Today I rewrote other parts of the user system and put it into a plugin. The Registration works completely fine on its own (data gets saved into the database and so on) but the email does not get sent anymore and I can't figure out why. ($user_login should be an email adress)

```
 private function custom_set_user_password($user_login){
    global $wpdb, $wp_hasher;

    $user_login = sanitize_text_field($user_login);
    
    if (empty($user_login) ) {
        return false;
    } else if (strpos( $user_login, '@' )) {
        $user_data = get_user_by('email', trim($user_login));
        if ( empty( $user_data ) )
        return false;
    } else {
        $login = trim($user_login);
        $user_data = get_user_by('login', $login);
    }

    do_action('lostpassword_post');

    if (!$user_data) {
        return false;
    } 

    $user_login = $user_data->user_login;
    $user_email = $user_data->user_email;

    do_action('retrieve_password', $user_login);

    $allow = apply_filters('allow_password_reset', true, $user_data->ID);

    if (!$allow){
        return false;
    }
    else if (is_wp_error($allow)) {
        return false;
    }
        
    $key = wp_generate_password( 20, false );
    do_action( 'retrieve_password_key', $user_login, $key );

    if (empty($wp_hasher)) {
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php';
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(12, true );
    }
    $hashed = time() . ':' . $wp_hasher->HashPassword($key);
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array( 'user_activation_key' => $hashed ), array('user_login' => $user_login) );

    $message = "example";
    $message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'https') . ">\r\n";

    $site_name = 'Set your Password'; 

    $title = sprintf('[%s] Set Password', $site_name);
    $title = apply_filters('retrieve_password_title', $title);
    $message = apply_filters('retrieve_password_message', $message, $key);

    $sent = wp_mail($user_email, $title, $message);

    if (!$sent) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Do I have to configure something differently when using it in a plugin or have i overlooked something in my code?

Side question: wp_mail() is using SMTP to send mails right? If yes, where exactly are the configurations for it?

Btw: I am coding on a localhost, I uploaded my files to a deployment-server and tested it that way.

Comment: if you do not set SMTP details then it will just use the servers provided mail routine ( usually sendmail ), which your host provides. This means there's a very high chance it'll just arrive in spam

Comment: It didn't arrive in spam and I tried it with multiple mail providers. Also the server i use does use sendmail because the provider configured it that way. Can I change this to SMTP in my code or just via a plugin?

Comment: there are plugins, I couldn't recommend which one is the best but a quick search on .org will give results, otherwise you'd need to add more debugging information, e.g. we don't know the result of `wp_mail`, as your tests give no insight into the process other than did it work or not at the very end. For all we know the code never runs. Tools such as Mailhog can help test locally

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I tried a few different ways to solve this problem (with other php mailing libraries) which worked but not perfectly. Then I wrote it back to sendmail / wp_mail() in my template, downloaded the SMTP Mail Plugin as suggested ( from WP Forms) and it works perfectly. Debugging with Mailhog was a great tip by the way, thanks a lot for that!